# rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 is deprecated warning

Tags: kubernetes

```
root@vsr-kub005:~# kubectl apply -f gitlab-admin-service-account.yaml
Warning: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 ClusterRoleBinding is deprecated in v1.17+, unavailable in v1.22+;
```

What will happen if I apply v1 instead of v1beta1?

Comment: Code is working fine with v1

Comment: Though the problem lies in v1.2

Comment: But I didn't mark it down initially.

Comment: Can you please describe more mike?

Comment: Thanks for the comment mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Warning: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 ClusterRoleBinding is deprecated in v1.17+, unavailable in v1.22+;

The warning is self-explanatory. In API `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` the `ClusterRoleBinding` object is deprecated and you won't able to use it in k8s version `v1.22+`.

The API `v1` is the stable version and you should always use the stable one if possible.

Comment: script to find all deprecations https://github.com/dguyhasnoname/k8s-day2-ops/blob/master/upgrade/k8s-deprecations.sh

Comment: See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122